# Grid Displayer Bookmarklet for Bootstrap 3 stopped working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3, bookmarklet

I was using [Grid Displayer Bookmarklet](http://alefeuvre.github.io/foundation-grid-displayer/) to visualize the gird for the plain HTML website I am creating. But since yesterday I noticed that it not working any more.
When I use the bookrmarklet on the Grid Displayer page itself it works and it also works on the getbootstrap.com but does display anything when I try it on the site I am building.

I am not able to understand why it's not working...was wondering if it's because the files are hosted locally on my pc... then again, it was working before!

One more thing, is there any way I could display the grid manually in Bootstrap 3 (like it's possible with some other frameworks by adding a special class to a tag)

Comment: I am okay if you guys are giving negative points to this question, but it would be good to know the reason. I have been trying to fix this for long time and and tried all possible option I could think of. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm Antoine, the creator of the Grid Displayer bookmarklet. I released about a week ago a new version including HTTPS support. The problem you're having made me realise that, while the HTTPS protocol was now supported, the FILE protocol wasn't any more! I've just made a quick rollback to make sure people like you using the bookmarklet on local files wouldn't be blocked. I now have to look for a solution which supports both the HTTPS and FILE protocols.

Sorry about that. If in the future you experience another problem, please report it on https://github.com/alefeuvre/foundation-grid-displayer/issues. I stumbled upon your StackO post by chance.

Comment: Thanks Antoine! It's working again!
You made my day!!  :)

Also, thanks for providing such a great tool!